# Using Java Stream groupingBy with both key and value of map

Tags: java, java-stream

Java 11 here. I have the following POJOs:

```
public enum Category {
    Dogs,
    Cats,
    Pigs,
    Cows;
}

@Data // using Lombok to generate getters, setters, ctors, etc.
public class LineItem {
    private String description;
    private Category category;
    private BigDecimal amount;
}

@Data
public class PieSlice {
    private BigDecimal value;
    private BigDecimal percentage;
}
```

I will have a `lineItemList : List<LineItem>` and want to convert them into a `Map<Category,PieSlice>` whereby:

- the `Category` key represents all the distinct `Category` values across all the `lineItemList` elements; and
- each `PieSlice` value is created such that:

  - its `value` is a sum of all the `LineItem#amount` that reference the same `Category`; and
  - its `percentage` is a ratio of the `PieSlice#value` (the sum of all `lineListItem` elements mapped to the `Category`) and the total amount of **all** `LineItem#amount`s combined

For example:

```
List<LineItem> lineItemList = new ArrayList<>();
LineItem dog1 = new LineItem();
LineItem dog2 = new LineItem();
LineItem cow1 = new LineItem();

dog1.setCategory(Category.Dogs);
dog2.setCategory(Category.Dogs);
cow1.setCategory(Category.Cows);

dog1.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(5.50);
dog2.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(3.50);
cow1.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.00);
```

Given the above setup I would want a `Map<Category,PieSlice>` that looks like:

- only has 2 keys, `Dogs` and `Cows`, because we only have (in this example) Dogs and Cows
- the `PieSlice` for Dogs would have:

  - a `value` of `9.00` because `5.50` + `3.50` is `9.00`; and
  - a `percentage` of `0.9`, because if we take the total amounts of all dogs + all cows, we have a total value of `10.0`; Dogs comprise `9.00 / 10.00` or `0.9` (90%) of the total animals
- the `PieSlice` for Cows would have:

  - a `value` of `1.00`; and
  - a `percentage` of `0.1`

My best attempt only yields a `Map<Category,List<LineItem>>` which is not what I want:

```
List<LineItem> allLineItems = getSomehow();
Map<Category,List<LineItem>> notWhatIWant = allLineItems.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LineItem::getCategory());
```

Can anyone spot how I can use the Streams API to accomplish what I need here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To collect to what you want, you need 2 steps, one to calculate the sum of the `LineItem` values (in your case `10.0`), and the other to collect into the map that you need.

First, get the overall sum, which we'll use later to divide the values.  The [`reduce` method sums up the values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).  The first argument is the identity value, in this case, `0`.  The second argument adds in each item as it comes, and the third argument combines two intermediate results.  Here, they're both `add`.

```
BigDecimal sum = lineItemList.stream()
                .map(LineItem::getAmount)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add, BigDecimal::add);
```

Then, create the `PieSlice`s.  This uses [the specific overload of `Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) that allows you to merge entries with the same key, so you can sum them up.

The first argument is the key extractor function, the second argument is the value extractor function, the third argument is the merging function, and the fourth (optional) is the map supplier function, in case you want a specific implementation of `Map`.

```
Map<Category, PieSlice> result = lineItemList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(LineItem::getCategory,
        li -> new PieSlice(li.getAmount(), li.getAmount().divide(sum, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)),
        (a, b) -> new PieSlice(a.getValue().add(b.getValue()), a.getPercentage().add(b.getPercentage())),
        HashMap::new));
```

This assumes that the indicated constructor for `PieSlice` is available, and if I add a suitable `toString` method in `PieSlice`, I get this map:

```
{Dogs=PieSlice{9.0, 0.90}, Cows=PieSlice{1.0, 0.10}}
```